# rails render using wrong asset path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am receiving the following error when trying to render a custom action in rails 5.1.4. I cant seem to figure out the issue, it seems like it must be something with the router parsing the params and determining the asset path? Its prepending the word blog for some reason... Blog is only a controller it doesnt have a database table..

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/blog/assets/js/custom.js")
```

routes.rb

```
get "/blog/:article_id", :to => "blog#article", as: 'blog_article'
```

blog_controller.rb

```
def article
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
end
```

Comment: I think there is no such file in assets folder - `assets/js/custom.js`

Answer (score 0):

issue was a relative path on the asset links from the application layout, sry